# Add 4 colors to the middle of a gradient

Tags: css, linear-gradients

To have 4 colors in the middle like this, what would this part of the code be changed to?

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 85px, #0000 85px),
linear-gradient(to top, teal 85px, #0000 85px);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5k94s01b/

I'm trying to add 4 colors in the middle of the square gradient.

That is all I am trying to figure out how to do.

How would it be added to the code?

I have not been able to figure out how to do it.

[image]

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

```css
.box {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;

  background-image:

    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 10px, #0000 10px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 10px, #0000 10px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 10px, #0000 10px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 10px, #0000 10px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 15px, #0000 15px),
    linear-gradient(to left, orange 15px, #0000 15px),
    linear-gradient(to top, orange 15px, #0000 15px),
    linear-gradient(to right, orange 15px, #0000 15px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 20px, #0000 20px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 20px, #0000 20px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 20px, #0000 20px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 20px, #0000 20px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 25px, #0000 25px),
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 25px, #0000 25px),
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 25px, #0000 25px),
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 25px, #0000 25px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 30px, #0000 30px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 30px, #0000 30px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 30px, #0000 30px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 30px, #0000 30px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 35px, #0000 35px),
    linear-gradient(to left, orange 35px, #0000 10px),
    linear-gradient(to top, orange 35px, #0000 35px),
    linear-gradient(to right, orange 35px, #0000 35px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 40px, #0000 40px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 40px, #0000 40px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 40px, #0000 40px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 40px, #0000 40px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 45px, #0000 45px),
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 45px, #0000 45px),
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 45px, #0000 45px),
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 45px, #0000 45px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 50px, #0000 50px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 50px, #0000 10px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 50px, #0000 50px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 50px, #0000 50px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 55px, #0000 55px),
    linear-gradient(to left, orange 55px, #0000 10px),
    linear-gradient(to top, orange 55px, #0000 55px),
    linear-gradient(to right, orange 55px, #0000 55px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 60px, #0000 60px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 60px, #0000 60px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 60px, #0000 60px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 60px, #0000 60px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 65px, #0000 65px),
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 65px, #0000 65px),
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 65px, #0000 65px),
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 65px, #0000 65px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 70px, #0000 70px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 70px, #0000 70px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 70px, #0000 70px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 70px, #0000 70px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 75px, #0000 75px),
    linear-gradient(to left, orange 75px, #0000 75px),
    linear-gradient(to top, orange 75px, #0000 75px),
    linear-gradient(to right, orange 75px, #0000 75px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 80px, #0000 80px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 80px, #0000 80px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 80px, #0000 80px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 80px, #0000 80px),

    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 85px, #0000 85px),
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 85px, #0000 85px);
   
  background-size: 170px 170px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Is `#0000` meant to be `#000`? I'm not sure CSS hex colours support a 4 digit syntax.

Comment: I'm looking into it now. And thank you for that information.

Comment: I found this: "The CSS 4-digit hex color notation is shorthand for the 8-digit hex notation." https://www.quackit.com/css/color/values/css_hex_color_notation_4_digits.cfm

Comment: Is using #0000 for transparent fairly new?

Comment: Not really, just very uncommon. Many forget that this syntax exists and is valid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple instances of a square gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693545/multiple-instances-of-a-square-gradient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [сonic-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient()) for the bottom background layer:

```css
.сoncentric-squares-with-center-multicolor {
  width: 170px; height: 170px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 10px, #0000 10px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 10px, #0000 10px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 15px, #0000 15px),
    linear-gradient(to left, orange 10px, #0000 10px),
    linear-gradient(to top, orange 10px, #0000 10px),
    linear-gradient(to right, orange 15px, #0000 15px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 20px, #0000 20px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 15px, #0000 15px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 15px, #0000 15px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 20px, #0000 20px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 25px, #0000 25px),
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 20px, #0000 20px),
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 20px, #0000 20px),
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 25px, #0000 25px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 30px, #0000 30px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 25px, #0000 25px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 25px, #0000 25px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 30px, #0000 30px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 35px, #0000 35px),
    linear-gradient(to left, orange 30px, #0000 30px),
    linear-gradient(to top, orange 30px, #0000 30px),
    linear-gradient(to right, orange 35px, #0000 35px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 40px, #0000 40px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 35px, #0000 35px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 35px, #0000 35px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 40px, #0000 40px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 45px, #0000 45px),
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 40px, #0000 40px),
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 40px, #0000 40px),
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 45px, #0000 45px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 50px, #0000 50px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 45px, #0000 45px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 45px, #0000 45px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 50px, #0000 50px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 55px, #0000 55px),
    linear-gradient(to left, orange 50px, #0000 50px),
    linear-gradient(to top, orange 50px, #0000 50px),
    linear-gradient(to right, orange 55px, #0000 55px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 60px, #0000 60px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 55px, #0000 55px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 55px, #0000 55px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 60px, #0000 60px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 65px, #0000 65px),
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 60px, #0000 60px),
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 60px, #0000 60px),
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 65px, #0000 65px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 70px, #0000 70px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 65px, #0000 65px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 65px, #0000 65px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 70px, #0000 70px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 75px, #0000 75px),
    linear-gradient(to left, orange 70px, #0000 70px),
    linear-gradient(to top, orange 70px, #0000 70px),
    linear-gradient(to right, orange 75px, #0000 75px),
    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 80px, #0000 80px),
    linear-gradient(to left, black 75px, #0000 75px),
    linear-gradient(to top, black 75px, #0000 75px),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 80px, #0000 80px),
    
    /* For the latest browsers: */
    conic-gradient(at 85px 85px, #3f48cc 0deg 90deg, #f00 90deg 180deg, #ff0 180deg 270deg, #99D9EA 270deg 360deg),
    /* or browsers that do not support conic-gradient: */
    left 85px top 85px / 165px 165px linear-gradient(45deg, #3f48cc 0px 59px, #0000 59px 175px, #ff0 175px 233px),     
    left 85px top 85px / 165px 165px linear-gradient(-45deg, #99D9EA 0px 60px, #0000 60px 175px, #f00 175px 233px),    
    left 60px top 60px / 82px 82px linear-gradient(-135deg, #3f48cc 0px 60px, #0000 60px 175px, #ff0 175px 233px),    
    left 60px top 60px / 82px 82px linear-gradient(135deg, #f00 0px 61px, #0000 61px 175px, #99d9ea 175px 233px);
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  /* background-position: 0 0; default */
  /* background-repeat: repeat; default */
}

body { margin: 0; min-height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; }
```

```html
<div class="сoncentric-squares-with-center-multicolor"></div>
```